# How to show a view with only selected item from an array list in Knockout JS?

Tags: knockout.js

I have created a sample jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/nair/bv3FG/19/ to demonstrate the problem I am running into. I have a collection of person, I show them in a table, with an option to edit each row. The data display properly on load. But when I go to edit model I face two problems;

1. I need to make sure when I edit a row, I want the edit template to
   show but not the table. I am using visibility to toggle visibility.
   This does seem to work.
2. When I press edit, the form shows to edit but my selected item data
   does not show, even though in the template I am passing, the
       selected item as the data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that it errors out trying to bind immediately against your selecteditem which is an empty array.

A better strategy is probably to use the `with` binding against `selecteditem` to control the context of that section.  If `selecteditem` is empty, then that area will not be rendered.

So, it would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ACE2d/

Then, you don't need to use visibility on your form, as the `with` binding will take care of it.  After saving, you can mark the item as null and the area will no longer be visible/bound.

Comment: +1 Agreed, the with binding is ideal for this scenario. other options are to use the if (but then you dont get the context change) or use visible (but then it still tries to bind the internals so you have to nest some if's too). one other way is to use a named external template to wrap around the form and still use the "With"