# Edit item in knockout observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I am looking for an example where i can show an observableArray as normal text with edit / delete links.  Items can be added/edited from a separate form.
I am not able to edit the record from edit link it add new record!

> ```
>  self.editItem = function (p) {
>         //edit code
>         ////???????
>     };
> ```

[Here is example](http://jsfiddle.net/JnjFf/3/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other mentioned in there answers, you should use `with` binding for editing any particular record. Here i have created a demonstration according to your need.

http://jsfiddle.net/85afB/1/

Answer (score 2):

You have to track the particular item which is going to be edit (have it observable) and use [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html). See full example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356505/209459) (jsFiddle).

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ACE2d/) is link to the jsfiddle from Petr's reference.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you are asking but if you are wanting to put the values back into the edit boxes then try this:

```
self.editItem = function (p) {
    self.FirstName(p.FirstName);
};
```

Will then just have to write your logic to check if it already exists