# Editing records using MVC Knockout.js dropdown lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js

I've got a normalized database with members, our fiscal calendar which starts in April with an ID of 1, and membership types of 1 for Basic or 2 for Advanced.

I could have a record in the database that looks like 1234 for the member ID, 3 because the member's membership expires in June, and 2 because the member has an Advanced membership.

I have an MVC project and I am learning how to use Knockout. I do not know how to implement an interface to allow a user to change a member's membership expiration month and membership level using dropdown lists.

I was able to implement some filtering where I have a list of all of my fiscal months and membership types and I had to use a "selectedMonth" and "selectedLevel" observable to track which options were selected by the users.

I am not sure how this applies to when I am editing a record though. All examples I find only use text boxes.

I need help with setting up my view model which will be passed to Knockout. I am going to have a list of members. Should each member have

MemberID as String
FiscalCalendarItems as list of FiscalCalendarItem
SelectedFiscalCalendarID as Integer
MembershipItems as list of MembershipItem
SelectedMembershipID as Integer

OR should I have separate models 1.) memberID, fiscalCalendarID, selectedMembershipID, 2.) FiscalCalendarItems, 3.) MembershipItems?

Comment: honestly speaking i don't understand your question clearly, but as far as editing is concerned you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365227/edit-item-in-knockout-observablearray/15366890#15366890

Comment: Thank you I am interested in finding a similar example that uses dropdown lists. When the user edits membership type, there are two types of memberships id=1 name="Basic" & id=2 name="Advanced". Currently, the interface displays 1. I want it to read "Basic" so the user has the option to select "Advanced". My list of members loads correctly my viewmodel. I am not sure how the choices for the dropdown fields fit in to my viewmodel. Can they be an observable array in my current viewmodel or do I need to make a separate viewmodel to store the selectable values for the list?

Comment: No need to make a separate viewModel, you can create an observableArray (name may be selectedItems) as a property in the current viewModel

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help. I ended up passing my viewModel 3 parameters (data, fiscalPeriods, memberTypes). Then, I let mapping do the rest!